# How to use a variable inside a function which is defined (variable) in some other function within a class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real=real
        self.imaginary=imaginary  
    def __add__(self, no):
        self.real=self.real+no.real
        self.imaginary=self.imaginary+no.imaginary
    def __str__(self):
        if self.imaginary == 0:
            result = "%.2f+0.00i" % (self.real)
        else:
            result = "%.2f+%.2fi" % (self.real, self.imaginary)
```

I want to print the sum of two complex numbers inside **add** function in the format defined in **str** method without manipulating the **str** function.
Meaning how can I access the result variable defined in the **str** method from the **add** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand your question you want to print result of **str** method inside **add**. So i think this is the best decision:

```
class Complex(object):
def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
    self.real = real
    self.imaginary = imaginary

def __add__(self, no):
    self.real = self.real + no.real
    self.imaginary = self.imaginary + no.imaginary
    print(str(self))

def __str__(self):
    if self.imaginary == 0:
        result = "%.2f+0.00i" % (self.real)
    else:
        result = "%.2f+%.2fi" % (self.real, self.imaginary)
    return result

a = Complex(1, 2)
b = Complex(3, 4)
a + b
```

Comment: yes, it worked fine. But can you please explain me how actually this str(self) works here. How it is printing the output in the format as defiened in the result variable of __str__ method. Is it some special way of calling a method.

Comment: @Saurabh When u use str(object) magic method __str__ of object will be called.  [python docs for __str__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)